# YouTube v3 api using code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/youtube/v3

Tags: go, youtube-api, google-api-go-client

Trying to grab a list of uploads from my channel but I get the error "ChannelContentDetails has no field or method Uploads"

```
apiCall := youtube.Channels.List("contentDetails").Mine(true)
response, err := apiCall.Do()
if err != nil {
log.Fatalf("Error making API call: %v", err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(response.Items[0].ContentDetails.uploads)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
response.Items[0].ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads
```

should work.